# ARC static library compatibility

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a static library that I developed using ARC and then compiled into a binary and I was wondering what the limitations would be on someone else using this library.  Specifically what is the minimum iOS that it will be able to run on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is a compiler technology.

If you used `weak` references at any point then you'll be relying on parts of the runtime that were added only in iOS 5.0. So the prima facie answer is "5.0".

However if your user is willing also to link to something like [MAZeroingWeakRef](https://github.com/mikeash/MAZeroingWeakRef), which adds those parts of the runtime that are required to support weak but only if they're not already present, then compatibility could go back to iOS 2.0.

Comment: So if I am not using weak references it will be fine and if I am using weak references what will happen?  They won't get automatically nilled out upon release?

Comment: @strikerdude10 no, if you're using `weak` references and someone includes your library on iOS 4.0 without also including `MAZeroingWeakRef` or an equivalent solution then your application will fail to launch. The compiler will have inserted calls to a C function that the dynamic linker will determine isn't present once it's finished loading everything so it'll raise an exception rather than pass execution to the program. Use `unsafe_unretained` in place of `weak` if that's an issue and if you can deal with non-weak references.